# find several words beginning spaced by a maximum number of other words

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my regexp to find several begin of words, separated by a fixed number of other words (here 0 or 1):

```
\b(Word1.*\b(?:\w{0,1})\bWord2.*\b(?:\w{0,1})\bWord3.*)\b
```

And here the text, with between brackets the block I want to find:

Now, is the result of 'match' operation in the same text. What I Want is between [], and what the c# RegExp engine find is between {}:

Wanted and Found:

```
1) aaa {[Word1 Word2 Word3] bbb}
2) aaa {[Word1 xxx Word2 xxx Word3] bbb}
3) aaa {[Word1nn xxx Word2nn xxx Word3nn] bbb}
```

Not wanted and not found:

```
4) aaa mmWord1nn xxx mmWord2nn xxx mmWord3nn bbb
```

Not wanted and found :

```
5) aaa {Word1nn xxx xxx Word2nn xxx Word3nn bbb}
6) aaa {Word1nn xxx xx Word2nn xxx xxx Word3nn bbb}
7) aaa {Word1 xxx Word2 xxx xxx Word3 bbb}
8) aaa {Word1 xxx xx Word2 xxx xxx Word3 bbb}
```

So, my problems are:

- on 1) to 3), where the end of sentence is found too, but i don't want it;
- on 5) to 8), where words are separated by more than {0,1} other words, but which are found by regexp engine.

Any solutions?

Comment: What language are you using? Please edit your question and add the appropriate language tag. And please clarify your question - with regex questions a good way to do that is show input and expected output of match - shown separately

Comment: What this line means `Wanted between [], and found between {}:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like this which should work on most languages:

```
\b(Word1\S* (?:\S+ )?Word2\S* (?:\S+ )?Word3\S*)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM3sW0/1)

Notes:

`\w` matches a single (word) character from the (rough) character class `[A-Za-z0-9]`, and not a word. Use `\S+` to mean a word (a series of non space characters).

Use `\S*` instead of `.*` because `.` will match spaces too.

Comment: It's ok for a part of answer. But I can not control the number of words between. How to do that ?

Comment: @francois.piondrancy You change the `?`. You can use `{0,1}` instead of the `?` and if you do that, you can change the number `1` to another number where the number will limit the number of words in between. E.g. `(?:\S+ ){0,2}` will allow up to 2 words between the required words.

Comment: If you want *any* number of words, turn it into `*?`: `(?:\S+ )*?`

Comment: +1 for nice fix, looks like Francois could probably also drop his outer parentheses :)

Comment: @zx81 Thanks. Didn't notice it in the spur of the moment, but yes, the capture group can be removed. I just hope he won't be confused if his `match.Groups[1].Value` is empty if he does that. ^^